# Handling mapping table in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my application, there will be multiple investors tagged for single purchase entry. So on loading a purchase entry, I should get all the investors associated.

In my controller,

```
return response()->json(GoldPurchase::with('investors')->get());
```

Mapping table schema,

```
Schema::create('gold_purchase_investor', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('investor_id')->unsigned();
   $table->integer('purchase_id')->unsigned();
   $table->timestamps();

   $table->foreign('investor_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('investors')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

   $table->foreign('purchase_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('gold_purchases')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Purchase model,

```
class GoldPurchase extends Model
{
    public function investors() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\GoldPurchaseInvestor');
    }
}
```

Investor model,

```
class Investor extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'address', 'mobile', 'email'];

    public function purchases() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\GoldPurchase');
    }
}
```

PurchaseInvestor model,

```
class GoldPurchaseInvestor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'gold_purchase_investor';

    public function purchase() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\GoldPurchase');
    }

    public function investor() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Investor');
    }
}
```

With this, I am getting error,

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gold_purchase_investor.gold_purchase_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `gold_purchase_investor` where `gold_purchase_investor`.`gold_purchase_id` in (1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the custom foreign key:

```
public function investors() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\GoldPurchaseInvestor', 'purchase_id');
}
```

But this is actually a case for a [`BelongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship:

```
public function investors() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Investor', 'gold_purchase_investor', 'purchase_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships):

> Remember, Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on the  Comment model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id. So, for this example, Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the  Comment model is post_id.

```
$this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

So try to write your foreign key and local key in the relationships

In your case I think it would be something like that:

```
class GoldPurchase extends Model`
{
    public function investors() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\GoldPurchaseInvestor', 'investor_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: This one gives me the mapping table data (both ids). How to get data from investors table using this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Use `belongsToMany` for many-to-many relationships.

**GoldPurchase.php**

```
class GoldPurchase extends Model{
    public function investors() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Investor','gold_purchase_investor','purchase_id','investor_id');
    }
}
```

**Investor.php**

```
class Investor extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'address', 'mobile', 'email'];

    public function purchases() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\GoldPurchase','gold_purchase_investor','investor_id','purchase_id');
    }
}
```

You don't need a third model for pivot table at all. 
`GoldPurchaseInvestor` is not at all needed.